# How to link PHP backhand to cognito Developer Authenticated Identities for creating the token of the user which will login from android client?

Tags: php, android, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, aws-php-sdk

I'm working on the android application which has the backhand in PHP and its has its own authentication process.I have an requirement to save the images related to the specific user on the **Amazon web services** using the **S3 storage service**.As we have the our own authentication process I don't want to user any social public Auth provider (like Facebook,Google etc..).So I decided to user the **Developer Authenticated Identities** in **Cognito service** available in amazon.So is their any blog,any sample code available that u know so that i can start the coding in short any one can give me brief overview or logic how can i implement it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the examples for using the low level SDK for Cognito here : 
http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/TxBVEDL5Z8JKAC/Use-Amazon-Cognito-in-your-website-for-simple-AWS-authentication

This explains the flow for developer authenticated identities : http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx2FL1QAPDE0UAH/Understanding-Amazon-Cognito-Authentication-Part-2-Developer-Authenticated-Ident

So Instead of implementing the basic auth flow, you need to implement the developer authenticated identities authflow.

**Edit 2015-02-18**

We've released an end-to-end sample with a [Java backend](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-cognito-developer-authentication-sample) and [iOS](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/master/CognitoSync-Sample/Objective-C) and [Android](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/CognitoSyncDemo) clients. [This blog post](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx3E3NJURV1LNV1/Integrating-Amazon-Cognito-using-developer-authenticated-identities-An-end-to-en) explains the samples in further detail.